# Who created an Amazon EC2 instance using Boto and Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-cloudtrail

I want to know who created a particular instance. I am using Cloud Trail to find out the statistics, but I am not able to get a particular statistics of who created that instance. I am using Python and Boto3 for finding out the details.
I am using this code- Lookup events() from Cloud trail in boto3, to extract the information about an instance.

```
ct_conn = sess.client(service_name='cloudtrail',region_name='us-east-1')


events=ct_conn.lookup_events()
```

Comment: Can you download the CloudTrail logs, filter for RunInstances, locate the specific instance ID and then retrieve the user identity from that log?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?? or how to approach this using Boto?

Comment: please show the code you are attempting to use, @upaangsaxena.

Comment: @upaangsaxena Sorry, I have not used the boto CloudTrail API. The documentation is minimal and I see no good examples of how to use it.

Comment: You don't need a code to find out that from CloudTrail. Please navigate to CloudTrail in the AWS Console and filter using date

Comment: If you had AWS Config setup - then those details are directly out of the box

Comment: I found out the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the solution to the above problem using lookup_events() function.

```
ct_conn = boto3.client(service_name='cloudtrail',region_name='us-east-1')

events_dict= ct_conn.lookup_events(LookupAttributes=[{'AttributeKey':'ResourceName', 'AttributeValue':'i-xxxxxx'}])
for data in events_dict['Events']:
    json_file= json.loads(data['CloudTrailEvent'])
    print json_file['userIdentity']['userName']
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire code if possible or can you also mention the line where you defined "sess" before using it in the line "ct_conn = sess.client(service_name='cloudtrail',region_name='us-east-1')"

Comment: You can define the session object just above the ct_conn line.

Answer (score 0):

@Karthik - Here is the sample of creating session

```
import boto3
import json
import os

session = boto3.Session(region_name='us-east-1',aws_access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])

ct_conn = session.client(service_name='cloudtrail',region_name='us-east-1')

events_dict= ct_conn.lookup_events(LookupAttributes=[{'AttributeKey':'ResourceName', 'AttributeValue':'i-xxx'}])

for data in events_dict['Events']:
    json_file= json.loads(data['CloudTrailEvent'])
    print (json_file['userIdentity']['userName'])
```