# How do I get IAM user owner for any particular AWS resource using Boto & Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3

I'm trying to get the User Owner of any particular AWS resource, be it instance, volume, security group etc..

I searched but could not find any helpful information apart from this
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596873/who-created-an-amazon-ec2-instance-using-boto-and-python),
This is what I found closer [The answer suggests we can get the user who created an instance] to what I'm looking for but still couldn't use it as the code mentioned is not complete.

If I consider the code from above mentioned post's answer, the following line

`ct_conn = sess.client(service_name='cloudtrail',region_name='us-east-1')`

is mentioned without defining the "**sess**".

Comment: Why not just use AWS CLI, it is inherently faster than anything in Python. You could also put it in your code by using shell out. Something along the lines of this would work: `aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids instance-id`, edit: and the output is in JSON

Comment: I don't get it, how do I get user information from `aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids instance-id`

Comment: Just replace `instance-id` with whatever the id is, should be something like `i-bunch_of_numbers_letters` and it will return you all the information about that instance in a JSON format

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy : Please use common sense. Service can be brought up and terminate without a trace, what make you think describe-* will keep this info?   Cloudtrails is mean for log all this activities.

Answer (score 1):

AWS will not records any AWS user activities info unless you setup [Cloudtrail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html) and send those info to S3 repository.